# On a family of $C^0$-convergent   Riemann metrics

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes

I am  dealing with the following concrete situation that could be familiar to  Riemannian geometers more experienced than myself.

Suppose that $M$ is a smooth compact  manifold of dimension $m$ and $g$ is a smooth Riemann  metric on $M$. $\newcommand{\ve}{{\varepsilon}}$ $\newcommand{\pa}{\partial}$  Suppose that $(g^\ve)_{\ve>0}$ is a family of smooth   Riemann metrics satisfying the following properties.

**A.**  We know that for any $p\in M$ there exists an open neighborhood $U\ni p$ and local coordinates $x^1,\dotsc, x^m$ on $U$ such that

$$  g^\ve_{ij} \to g_{ij} $$

uniformly  on  the compacts of $U$, where

$$ g^\ve =\sum_{i,j} g^\ve_{ij}dx^idx^j,\;\;g=\sum_{i,j}g_{ij}dx^idx^j. $$

**B.** (*Edited following Deane Yang's inquiry.*) The note by $Gr_2(TM)$ the bundle  of Grassmanians of $2$-planes in the tangent bundle. The sectional curvature $K^\ve$ can then be viewed as  a function $K^\ve: Gr_2(TM)\to\mathbb{R}$.  We know that  there exists a smooth function $K^0: Gr_2(TM)\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $K^\ve\to K^0$ uniformly.

**Question.** Can we conclude that the function $K^0$ in  **B** is the sectional curvature of $g$?

Comment: I just want to confirm that the sectional curvature converges only for co-ordinate 2-planes and not for other 2-planes? Others can answer your question better than me, but my experience has been that controlling the sectional curvature only along co-ordinate 2-planes (for a fixed set of co-ordinates) is not enough.

Comment: It's a bit better than the uniform convergence mentioned in my question.  let me edit the question.

Comment: Have you looked at the paper by Stefan Peters, "Convergence of riemannian manifolds", Compositio Math 62 (1987) 3-16? You can't conclude that the limiting sectional curvature is continuous but it is bounded almost everywhere.

Comment: I have looked at the paper you mentioned. That paper uses only the assumption that $K^\varepsilon$ is  uniformly bounded.  In my case $K^\varepsilon$ is convergent to a smooth limit. The question is weather this limit is indeed the curvature of the limiting metric  $g$ which we know is smooth.

Comment: You're absolutely right, and Anton Petrunin has a much better answer to your question.

Comment: Also, what exactly do you mean by the statement "$K^0$ is the sectional curvature of $g$"?

Comment: @ Deane   This means that for any $p\in M$ and for any $2$-plane $\pi\subset T_pM$ the scalar $K^0(\pi)$ is the sectional curvature of $g$ along $\pi$.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is true.
Here is a sketch of proof, but I am sure that there is a simper way to see it.

Note that by Gauss–Bonnet, this is true in dimension 2.

Assume we know it in dimension $n-1$.

There is a construction of smooth convex hypersurfaces $H^\varepsilon$ in $(M,g^\varepsilon)$
which converge nicely to a smooth hypersurfaces $H$ in $(M,g^\varepsilon)$.
"Nicely" means that one can apply the induction hypothesis for $H^\varepsilon\to H$.
Taking many hypersurfaces like that plus linear algebra finishes the proof.

**The construction.** To construct $H^\varepsilon$ near $p\in M$,
choose n points $a_1,a_2,\dots a_n$ such that 
in all the metrics the angles $\angle a_ipa_j\approx\pi/2$ for all $i\ne j$.
Then define
$$H^\varepsilon=\{\\, x\in M\mid \sum\phi(|a_i-x|_{g^\varepsilon}-|a_i-p|_{g^\varepsilon})= 0 \\,\}$$
where $\phi(0)=0$, $\phi'(0)=1$ and $\phi''\ll -2$.

Comment: @ Anton Thank you for your answer. I need to process  the strategy that you outlined above. I have to admit that I do not see why $H^\varepsilon$ is smooth and  what is the role of the angle condition that you mentioned.

Comment: @Liviu, sorry, it is very cryptic. Look at 4.3 in our "Extremal subsets in ..." and then look at Lemma B.5 in http://journals.tubitak.gov.tr/math/issues/mat-03-27-1/mat-27-1-9-0303-19.pdf
. Hope it helps.

Comment: @ Anton: Thanks for the ref. I'll check it out.

Comment: @Anton: Perhaps it is obvious, but why does it follow from Gauss-Bonnet in dimension 2?

Comment: @Dan. Fix 3 very close points, let $\triangle^\varepsilon$ be geodesic triangles for $g^\varepsilon$ with the vertices at these points. 
Note that the angles and area of $\triangle^\varepsilon$ converge to the angles and area of $\triangle^0$. Apply Gauss–Bonnet.